# Python - Removing percentage of forest cover (pixels) of a raster based the percentage of forest loss of a gdf's column

Tags: python, raster, rasterio

I have a Boolean raster that shows forest cover as 1 and no-forest as 0. The spatial resolution is 500m.

My gdf brings the municipalities boundaries and one of the columns is the percentage of forest cover that each municipality lost within a period.

I want to remove the percentage of forest cover (pixels) of a raster based the percentage of forest loss of a gdf's column.
The pixels to be removed must come from the edges of the forest patches to the inside.

Here is what I came up with so far:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import rasterio
from rasterio import features
from scipy.ndimage import binary_erosion

# Load GeoPackage with municipality boundaries and deforestation percentage
municipalities = gpd.read_file("gdf_muni_defor.gpkg")

# Load raster
raster_path = "Forest_Raster_clip.tif"
with rasterio.open(raster_path) as src:
    raster = src.read(1).astype(float)
    profile = src.profile

    # Iterate over municipalities and subtract edges
    for index, row in municipalities.iterrows():
        municipality_mask = features.geometry_mask([row.geometry], out_shape=raster.shape, transform=src.transform)
        deforestation_percentage = row['pct_defor_actual']

        # Identify the forest edges using binary erosion
        forest_edges = binary_erosion(raster == 1, iterations=1)

        # Calculate the number of pixels to subtract based on the deforestation percentage
        pixels_to_subtract = int(deforestation_percentage / 100 * forest_edges.sum())

        # Identify the pixels to be removed based on the calculated percentage
        pixels_to_remove = forest_edges.nonzero()

        # Set the specified percentage of pixels to 0
        raster[pixels_to_remove[:pixels_to_subtract]] = 0

        output_raster_path = "file_modified.tif"
        with rasterio.open(output_raster_path, 'w', **profile) as dst:
            dst.write(raster, 1)
```

The problem is that I get a blank (all zeros) raster as output.

Here it is a sample of the files I am using.
gdf:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ORFmpVpYb6ZE1NJydKgSP2KHghpX51xK/view?usp=sharing

raster:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/11pc1-EEw9p7nTOOEwYfxPehEIU7Act5P/view?usp=sharing